Как привести тип файла к blob?
сервер выдает 415 ошибку unsoprted media type - подскажите - как правильно blob сформировать?
const blob = new Blob([file.file as BlobPart], { type: file.file?.type });
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', blob, file.name);

public upload({
        formData,
    }: {
        formData?: {
            file: Blob;
        },
    }): CancelablePromise<string> {
        return this.httpRequest.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/attached-file',
            formData: formData,
            mediaType: 'multipart/form-data',
        });
    }

upload({formData})


а в консоли, в заголовках запроса, какое значение заголовка content-type?

application/json

ну вот и ответ. дальше - сам?
